# Transpose a pair of columns into a single row

Tags: excel, transpose, vba

I have a two column, n row table in this format:

> 1 | Apple
>   2 | Orange
>   3 | Fruit
>   4 | Car

I need to reformat all of the data into one row like so:

> 1 | Apple | 2 | Orange | 3 | Fruit | 4  |Car

I am aware of Paste Special using Transpose, but that still gives me a row for each column.

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: What code have you tried?  Please post an example in your original post.

Comment: this is not transposing, this looks more like concatenating 1 or more row data into one row

Comment: What do you mean by `that still gives me a row for each column` ? Transpose will take the values from 4 rows (1 column) and paste it to 1 row (4 column).

Comment: There are 4 rows and 2 columns.  OP wants 1 row 8 columns.

Answer (score 2):

If `1` is in A2, the in C2:

```
=OFFSET($A2,COLUMN()/2,0)
```

and in D2:

```
=OFFSET($B2,COLUMN()/2-1,0)
```

then drag the formulae across as a pair.

[OFFSET](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/offset.php)
[COLUMN](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/column.php)